# how to fix armature not symmetrizing on the right axis?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

so, im a new blender user and wanted to start making animations for the player i just made. i was trying to hit symmetrize like the video i was following told me but when i pressed it my armature changed on a different axis. i attached a screenshot of the issue. tysm <3[image]

Comment: Symmetrize will mirror your armature on X and will use the origin as center of the symmetry, this is what's happening here

Comment: @moonboots how can i reset it to the right spot then?

Answer (score 3):

Symmetrize will mirror your armature on X and will use the origin as center of the symmetry, but here your armature is aligned with Y and its origin is not correctly placed. To fix that:

- In *Object* mode rotate your armature 90° on Z and apply the rotation and scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
- In *Edit* mode select the head of your spine bone (for example), press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, then in *Object* mode right click > *Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*:
- Symmetrize again

Comment: what would control A be on mac since i use a mac and control^+a doesn't work

Comment: Cmd A or Object > Apply > Rotation and Scale

Comment: thank u so much!!!